# react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillMount in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

* Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.

Please update the following components: SideEffect(NullComponent)
```

I am not using class component except for error boundary. I am getting below error always.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/66045965/16967562